# Showing a pair of vectors is another orthogonal basis of $U$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U = span\{(2, 1, 3, -4), (1, 2, 0, 1)\}$

Show that $\{(1, 0, 2, -3), (4, 7, 1, 2)\}$ is another orthogonal basis of $U$.

I have an idea that the pair of vectors in the second set are $f_1$ and $f_2$, so I'm supposed to use the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization algorithm,

$f_1 = x_1$

$f_2 = x_2 - \frac{x_2 \cdot f_1}{||f_1||^2}f_1$

and solve for $x_2$, but now sure how.

Comment: You just need to show that the two new vectors belong to $U$ and are orthogonal; this suffices since orthogonality of nonzero vectors implies linear independence and $U$ is $2$-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $(1,0,2,-3) = (2/3)(2,1,3,-4) - (1/3)(1,2,0,1)$ and $(4,7,1,2) = (1/3)(2,1,3,-4) + (10/3)(1,2,0,1)$, so both $(1,0,2,-3)$ and $(4,7,1,2)$ belong to $U$. They are clearly orthogonal, and, in particular, linearly independent. Hence they must be a basis of $U$, which is $2$-dimensional.